# How to display this jquery as bold

Tags: jquery

Simple question which I cannot actually figure out how to solve, how can I make `.text(totalweight)` to be displayed as bold?

Below is the code:

```
$("#total-weight").text(totalweight).append('%');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$("#total-weight").text(totalweight).append('%').css('font-weight', '700');
```

As Moak has also shown, you can use `bold` as the value for font-weight, though using a number offers more precise control. [w3schools has more information](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp), and explains why I used 700 for the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#total-weight").css({fontWeight:'bold'}).text(totalweight).append('%');
```

for just the number:

```
$("#total-weight").html('<b>'+totalweight+'</b>').append('%');
```